# Problem getting relationship between entries to work

Tags: relations

I'm having trouble getting what should be a simple relationship between 2 channels to work as expected.

This is how things are set up.

Channel: Apprenticeships - essentially categories, types of apprenticeship (health, construction, catering etc)

Channel: Vacancies - individual apprenticeship courses  - each one related to an Apprenticehips entry.

In my template I can show a list of all Vacancy entries with

```
{% set vacancies = craft.entries.section("vacancies").find() %}
```

Then loop through them and output field data. This works fine and shows all the vacancy entries.

But I want to be able to filter the entries returned to those that are related to a specific Apprenticeships entry. This filtering is to be based on the third url segment, which is the slug of the Apprenticeship entry.

```
{% for cat in craft.entries.title(craft.entries.slug(craft.request.segment(3)).limit(1).find()) %}
```

This works fine and I can output field data from that Apprenticeship entry. Proving, in my mind, that Craft knows which entry I want.

To get only the Vacancy entries that are related to the Apprenticeship entry represented by cat I thought I could simply use 'cat' in another craft.entries tag.

```
{% set vacancies = craft.entries.section("vacancies").relatedTo(cat) %}
```

Then loop through vacancies outputting the vacancy field data. But it doesn't return any Vacancy entries even though there definitely some to return.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend doing it like so:

```
{% set vacancies = craft.entries.section('vacancies').limit(null) %}

{% set catSlug = craft.request.segment(3) %}

{% if catSlug %}
    {% set cat = craft.entries.section('apprenticeships').slug(catSlug).first() %}

    {% if cat %}
        {% set vacancies = vacancies.relatedTo(cat) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

This sets up an ElementCriteriaModel for all your Vacancies entries (don't use the `find()` method yet!).
Then checks for the first entry from the Apprenticeships section with a slug of your URL segment.
If there's really such an entry, it further extends the ElementCriteriaModel with a `relatedTo` parameter.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work either. In this case when a third segment is present it returns all the vacancies (related or not). When there is no third segment it shows nothing.

Comment: If I alter your code and use {% if catSlug %}
  {% set cat = craft.entries.slug(catSlug).first() %}
 {% endif %} then I get all vacancies when there is no third segment but nothing when there is a third segment.

Comment: and yes, I am on Craft Slack

Comment: This works perfectly. Part of the problem was my original code but the biggest issue was me testing with the wrong url!